# Regex for allowing one hyphen in between alphanumeric string of length 8

Tags: regex, validation

Tried this regex but not worked:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9]-\){8}$
```

Regex which matches:

```
112-4324

1d5g-5HU

ER9O5-11
```

But not matches:

```
112-234213421   (more than 8 chars)

1244-53         (less than 8 chars)

-23432BB        (hyphen at begining)

5tT569K-         (hyphen in the end)

234-23-5         (two hyphens)

RTG--43T          (two consecutive hyphens)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex based on lookahead:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{8}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY9zM3/2)

- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{8}$)` is positive lookahead to ensure there are 8 characters in input.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)` will make sure that `-` appears only once in the middle.

Comment: `(?=` starts a positive lookahead. [Read here for details on look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: and what if i want that 234-23-5  also to be validate true. This regex will work right `^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{8}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$`.

Comment: Yes that's almost right. `^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{8}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$` will work fine in that case.